# why I'm getting a error "withScriptjs is not exported from 'react-google-maps" in react js while using google map api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I'm working on a specific project, where I asked user to a pick location using a movable marker in google map.
I tested this code from stackoverflow which is given on the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588302/react-google-maps-how-does-one-get-marker-position/48777047#48777047) and [demolink](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mu8lid?file=MyParentComponentWrapper.js) and paste it in my computer but im getting this error continuesly.

> export 'withScriptjs' (imported as 'withScriptjs') was not found in 'react-google-maps' (possible exports: Circle, DirectionsRenderer, FusionTablesLayer, GoogleMap, InfoWindow, KmlLayer, Marker, OverlayView, Polygon, Polyline, Rectangle, StreetViewPanorama, TrafficLayer, __esModule, withGoogleMap)

MyParentComponentWrapper.js code:-

```jsx
import React from "react";
import { compose, withProps, lifecycle } from "recompose";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
} from "react-google-maps";

const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
  }),
  lifecycle({
    componentWillMount() {
      const refs = {};

      this.setState({
        position: null,
        onMarkerMounted: (ref) => {
          refs.marker = ref;
        },

        onPositionChanged: () => {
          const position = refs.marker.getPosition();
          console.log(position.toString());
        },
      });
    },
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)((props) => (
  <GoogleMap defaultZoom={8} defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}>
    {props.isMarkerShown && (
      <Marker
        position={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
        draggable={true}
        ref={props.onMarkerMounted}
        onPositionChanged={props.onPositionChanged}
      />
    )}
  </GoogleMap>
));

class MyParentComponentWrapper extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    isMarkerShown: false,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyMapComponent isMarkerShown={true} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyParentComponentWrapper;
```

App.js code:-

```jsx
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import "./App.css";
import MyParentComponentWrapper from "./MyParentComponentWrapper";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <MyParentComponentWrapper />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js code:-

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    
  </body>
</html>
```

package json

```
{
  "name": "map",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-google-maps/api": "^2.17.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

i just started learning react js and cannot figure out why im getting this error.

Comment: What version of the `react-google-maps` library have you installed? You should be able to see it in your `package.json` if you're not sure

Comment: FYI that library looks really out of date. The last update was 5 years ago

Comment: I agree with Phil about the library being outdated, I would recommend `react-google-maps/api`.

Comment: @Yrll  how can i update my api. when ever i use react-google-maps/api i get same error is there another way?

Comment: I noticed this on the error code "possible exports: Circle, DirectionsRenderer, FusionTablesLayer, GoogleMap, InfoWindow, KmlLayer, Marker, OverlayView, Polygon, Polyline, Rectangle, StreetViewPanorama, TrafficLayer, __esModule, withGoogleMap". The Library that you are using seem to not have the 'withScriptJs'. For what use are calling this?